# kernel source code for beaglebone black

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I want to build an Ubuntu kernel from  scratch for beaglebone black. I have been searching for where I can download the kernel source code for more than two days but haven't found anything.

So, please tell me from where I can get the kernel source code.

Comment: Do you want to compile the Ubuntu kernel specifically or the normal Linux kernel? How exactly did you search? The first result for [ubuntu kernel source code](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=ubuntu+kernel+source+code) tells you how to get the Ubuntu sources and the first result for [linux kernel source code](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+kernel+source+code&t=lm) is where you can download the stock kernel.

Comment: Actually I want to run Ubuntu on beaglebone black , but for this I don't want to use pre-build image. So, i need uboot, rootfs, kernel sourced code every thing so that i can compile my own image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result for ubuntu kernel source code in duckduckgo.com is https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode which explains the process of getting and compiling an Ubuntu kernel. I reproduce it here:

> All of the Ubuntu Kernel source is maintained under git. The source
>   for each release is maintained in its own git repository on
>   kernel.ubuntu.com. These can be browsed in gitweb, the official Ubuntu
>   trees are in the ubuntu/ directory. The Ubuntu Linux kernel git
>   repository is located at
>   git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-.git or
>   http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-.git. To
>   obtain a local copy you can simply git clone the repository for the
>   release you are interested in as below. The git command is part of the
>   git-core package:
>
> ```
> git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-<release>.git
> ```
>
> For example to obtain the maverick tree:
>
> ```
> git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-maverick.git
> ```
>
> This will download several hundred megabytes of data. If you plan on
>   working on more than one kernel release you can save space and time by
>   downloading the upstream kernel tree. Note that once these two trees
>   are tied together you cannot remove the virgin Linus tree without
>   damage to the Ubuntu tree:
>
> ```
> git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/linux.git
> git clone --reference linux git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-karmic.git
> git clone --reference linux git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-maverick.git
> ```
>
> In each case you will end up with a new directory ubuntu-
>   containing the source and the full history which can be manipulated
>   using the git command from within each directory.
>
> By default you will have the latest version of the kernel tree, the
>   master tree. You can switch to any previously released kernel version
>   using the release tags. To obtain a full list of the tagged versions
>   in the release as below:
>
> ```
> $ git tag -l Ubuntu-*
> Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.10
> Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.11
> Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.12
> Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.13
> Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.14
> $
> ```
>
> To look at the 2.6.27-7.13 version you can simply checkout a new
>   branch pointing to that version:
>
> ```
> git checkout -b temp Ubuntu-2.6.27-7.13
> ```
>
> You may then manipulate the release for example adding new commits.